# Does not work objectify example

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I have my entity with list of keys

```
List <Key<ManagerManager>> subordinates = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then i add some keys in `@ApiMethod`:

```
 Employee employee =ofy().load().key(Key.create(Employee.class, employeeId )).now();
           employee.getSubordinates().add(Key.create(ManagerManager.class, managerId));

        checkExists(employeeId);
        ofy().save().entity(employee).now();
```

End it saved [image]

After i want to get some Employees such as in [example](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#one-to-many-alternative)
and do somethin saving in datastore

```
Iterable<Employee> emploees = ofy().load().type(Employee.class).filter("subordinates", managerId);


        for (Employee item : emploees) {

            item.setEmail("Helloclone");
            ofy().save().entity(item).now();
        }
```

But  nothing happens. Where is a problem?

Comment: A key and the id are not the same. Try `Key.create(ManagerManager.class, managerId)` as filter criteria. So `filter("subordinates", Key.create(ManagerManager.class, managerId))`

Comment: @konqi, also does not working. I tried with Key.create(ManagerManager.class, managerId)

Comment: Was `subordinates` indexed (`@Index`) when the `Employees` were saved?

Comment: @tx802: yes. I did also that, but...

Comment: I want emphasise on tx802's comment: You have to make subordinates "indexed" before you create the entity having the email 2cloneMan. If you indexed later, the previously created entity cannot be indexed.